# Basic WebSocketSharp client connection in C#

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket-sharp

How do I get this to work:

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org"))
{
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
      Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE: " + e.Data);

    ws.Connect();
    ws.Send("TEST SEND");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

The error is:

```
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work if I use:

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org"))
```

Comment: So next time don't hold the s key too long so you get two s's instead of one s.